# New extension appears in admin menu but gives error 404 when i click on it

Tags: magento-1.9, 404, http-error-404

I have a Magento 1.9.2.4 store and I've installed an extension(by uploading everything that was in the archive trough ftp). It is now visible in the top menu bar in the admin section(it doesn't appear in `System > Configuration`) but when i click on it it leads me to the front of my store `404` error page.

I tried to reinstall the extension, then reset the roles(found that as a solution to a similar problem) then log out and in again but the problem is still there.

I was thinking about installing that extension trough Magento Connect but the same 404 error page appears when i click on `System > Magento Connect > Magento Monnect Manager`.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you logout from admin
2. Relogin then check
3. Clear cache and check in incognito browser
4. Sure it will work, Let me know if have any issue

Comment: Hey, i've done that but it doesn't work :(. I tried using another browser aswell but still nothing :(

Comment: Cleared the cache and used incognito, still not working :(